# Weird background appearing on links in dropdown navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and if you mouse over the "categories" navigation menu, you get a weird blue background in the links.

I set an overall background which is the gray, and the white for the link colors, but don't see any setting for that intermediate blue background.

Here is my css:

```
.menusystem 
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
}

.menusystem ul, .menusystem li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menusystem li 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.menusystem ul 
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menusystem ul li ul 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #5C5957; /* this gives the whole thing a background color */
}

.menusystem li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li 
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px; 

    display: block;
    float:right;

    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: solid 1px white;   
/*  line-height: 1em;   */
    height: 15px;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li_left
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;    
    margin-bottom: 7px;     

    display: block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;


/*  line-height: 1em;   */
    height: 15px;   
}

/* IE-Win (Holly hack) reads the list item line breaks, so lets hide those \*/
* html ul li { float: left; }
* html ul li a { height: 1%; }


.menusystem li:hover ul, .menusystem li.mouseHover ul { 
    display: block;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a
{
    color: #fff;


    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.last a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #ff0;
    background: #2e6ea4; 
}

/*.menusystem li.main_menu_li a */
.menusystem ul.child_menu_ul a
{
    color: #fff;            
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover 
{
    color: orange;
}
```

Any idea how I can just make the blue behind the links disappear?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given them a background and border of `#2e6ea4`. Either remove the lines indicated below or change the hex code.

```
.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4; /* delete or change this */
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4; /* delete or change this */
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4; /* delete or change this */
}
```

Comment: @GeekedOut: Also you might want to watch out for `.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover{ color: #ff0; background: #2e6ea4; }`. It will change them to the blue background on hover.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried inspecting the menu using dev tools ?
The `CSS` applied originates from [this](http://www.problemio.com/menusystem.css) file.

```
.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a
{
    color: #fff;


    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4; /* blue background */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The offenders are these properties:

```
.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a
{
    ...
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4;
}
```

Also, if you are using Chrome, open the Developer Tools window (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) to see which HTML elements are inheriting which CSS properties. If you are using Firefox, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for the same purpose.